# Child Component Isn't Updating with New Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having an issue getting my child component to update with new props. I'm deleting an item from the global state and it's successful. But when the item gets deleted, I'm expecting that item to no longer show. It's still being shown but if I were to move to another screen then back, it's gone. Any idea on what I might be missing here?

Thanks!!

```
export default class Summary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pickupData: this.props.pickup
    };
  }

  handleDelete(item) {
    this.props.deleteLocationItem(item);
  }

  render() {
    const pickup = this.state.pickup;

    return (
      <View>
        {pickup.map((item, i) => (
          <LocationItem
            name={item}
            onPressDelete={() => this.handleDelete(item)}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const LocationItem = ({ onPressDelete, name }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressDelete}>
    <Text>Hi, {name}, CLICK ME TO DELETE</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

------- Additional Info ------

```
case 'DELETE_LOCATION_INFO':
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
  pickup: state.pickup.filter(item => item !== action.action)
})

export function deleteLocationInfo(x){
  return {
    type: DELETE_LOCATION_INFO,
    action: x
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your deleteLocationItem function

Comment: `this.props.deleteLocationItem()` indicates that you are deleting the `item` in the parent to `Summary`, but you are putting `this.props.pickup` in the state of `Summary`, which means the `pickupData` in `Summary` will not update. You should probably use `this.props.pickup` instead of putting it in state at all.

Comment: You've got a syntax error in `this.state = {…}`

Comment: You are initializing your `state.pickupData` with `props.pickup` yet you are rendering items from `this.state.pickup`. Also there is no place where you update your state after `handleDelete` is executed. How is `this.state.pickup` initialized? What relation does it have to `props.pickup`? The code seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deleteLocationItem must be something like this:

```
deleteLocationItem(id) {
  this.setState({
   items: this.state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id)
  });
}
```

Then inside your Summary class you dont need to set the prop again. Just receive pickup from props like this:

```
render (

const { pickup } = this.props;
return(
  <View>
    { pickup.map
...
```

Comment: for some odd reason, `item.id` wasn't working for me. `item.id` and `item[id]` would be undefined but console.log(id) gave me each index #. eventually i did `deleteLocationItem(item) {
    this.setState({
     pickupData: this.state.pickupData.filter(data => data !== item )
   }, () => this.props.deleteLocationInfo(item));
  }` and that worked :D thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Render is happening based on the state which is  not updated other than in constructor. When the prop updates from parent, it is not reflected in the state.
Add componentWillReceiveProps method to receive new props and update state, which will cause new data to render

But more preferably, if the state is not being changed in any way after initialization, render directly using the prop itself which will resolve this issue